# three.js - X Y position INSIDE of a clicked plane

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

So I'm able to get the current object (this case a plane) under the mouse using a raycaster, but I'd like get an accurate X and Y for the mouse position INSIDE the plane.

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
    0.5 );

projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane, true);

if (intersects.length > 0) {
    console.log(intersects[0].point);
}
```

If I have my 200x200 plane facing the camera head on, then `intersects[0].point.x` ranges from -100 to +100 as expected. But when I rotate the plane I get mixed results.

How can I get an x value of -100 to +100 regardless of where the plane is on the scene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the intersected point in the object's local coordinate system when using `Raycaster`, do this:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3().copy( intersects[ 0 ].point );

intersects[ 0 ].object.worldToLocal( vector );

console.log( 'local point: ', vector );
```

three.js r.65

Comment: Hi @WestLangley, this method works for a rotated plane, but not if .updateMatrixWorld has been called on the intersecting object. Is that to be expected? three.js r85.

Comment: @MichaelRibbons Post a new question with all relevant information if you are having trouble.